# JsonConvert.SerializeObject is crashing in windows Xp sp3

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft json tool to serialize and de serialize.Previously i got circular reference json error, to resolve that i have used

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(NodeConfigurator.Instance, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
});
```

and it is working good in windows 7 and above , but in windows xp sp3 it is giving "**An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll**".  The exception message is **"'CommandConverter' is unable to convert 'abc.RelayCommand' to 'System.String'"**.  The InnerException is null.

The stacktrace message is

```
at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.GetConvertToException(Object value, Type destinationType)
at System.Windows.Input.CommandConverter.ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value, Type destinationType)
at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertToString(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertToInvariantString(Object value)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.TryConvertToString(Object value, Type type, String& s)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeString(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonStringContract contract)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObjectInternal(Object value, Type type, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object value, Type type, Formatting formatting, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object value, Formatting formatting, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
at uOPCDA.ViewModel.ShellVM.SaveToXmlFile(Nullable`1 result) in
```

I have tested with simple object and it is working good in xp also. But if the structure contains cyclic reference it is giving the above exception. Help me to solve this problem.

My Json output is like below in Windows 7.

```
{
   "LastSavedPath":"C:\Program Files (x86)\abc\uOPC Server\Lastclosed.uopf",
   "Channels":[
      {
         "NewDeviceCommand":{

         },
         "DeleteChannelCommand":{

         },
         "ChannelDoubleClickCommand":{

         },
         "Device":[
            {
               "NewTagCommand":{

               },
               "DeleteDevice":{

               },
               "IsNewTagCommandVisible":true,
               "IsDeleteDeviceVisible":true,
               "IsNewDeviceCommandVisible":true,
               "Tags":[
                  {
                     "IsEnableApplyBtn":false,
                     "TagName":"Tag1",
                     "TagAddress":"102364",
                     "TagNameimg":null,
                     "TagRightImg":null,
                     "TagDescription":"New",
                     "DataType":"Bool",
                     "ClientAccess":"Read Only",
                     "ScanRate":0,
                     "NewTag":null,
                     "NewGrpTag":null,
                     "DeleteCurGrpTag":null,
                     "MultiTagGen":null,
                     "ScalingNone":true,
                     "ScalingLinear":false,
                     "ScalingSquareRoot":false,
                     "RVRHigh":0,
                     "RVRLow":0,
                     "SVRData":"Double",
                     "SVRHigh":0,
                     "SVRHighClamp":false,
                     "SVRLow":0,
                     "SVRLowClamp":true,
                     "SVRUnits":null,
                     "NegateScalVal":true,
                     "Location":"DiscreteInputs",
                     "Address":"02364",
                     "Length":1
                  },
                  {
                     "IsEnableApplyBtn":false,
                     "TagName":"Tag2",
                     "TagAddress":"102365",
                     "TagNameimg":null,
                     "TagRightImg":null,
                     "TagDescription":"dfdfdf",
                     "DataType":"Bool",
                     "ClientAccess":"Read Only",
                     "ScanRate":0,
                     "NewTag":null,
                     "NewGrpTag":null,
                     "DeleteCurGrpTag":null,
                     "MultiTagGen":null,
                     "ScalingNone":true,
                     "ScalingLinear":false,
                     "ScalingSquareRoot":false,
                     "RVRHigh":0,
                     "RVRLow":0,
                     "SVRData":"Double",
                     "SVRHigh":0,
                     "SVRHighClamp":false,
                     "SVRLow":0,
                     "SVRLowClamp":true,
                     "SVRUnits":null,
                     "NegateScalVal":true,
                     "Location":"DiscreteInputs",
                     "Address":"02365",
                     "Length":1
                  }
               ],
               "DeviceModel":"Modbus",
               "DeviceName":"Device1",
               "AsciiDeviceID":"5",
               "AsciiDeviceIDType":"Decimal",
               "EtherNetDeviceID":null,
               "ScanMode":"",
               "ConnectionTimeout":3,
               "ScanRate":0,
               "IsAddedFirstDevice":false,
               "RequestTimeout":1000,
               "FailAfterSuccTimeout":3,
               "InterReqDelay":0,
               "EnableAutoDeviceDemotion":false,
               "DemotAftSuccFailure":0,
               "DemotForMS":0,
               "DiscardWriteReq":true,
               "StartUp":"Do not generate on startup",
               "Action":"Do not overwrite, log error",
               "PortNumber":"502",
               "IPProtocol":"",
               "AddtoGroup":0,
               "AllowAutoGenSubGrp":true,
               "UseZeroBasAdd":true,
               "UseZeroBitAddReg":false,
               "UseHoldRegBitMask":false,
               "UseModFun06RegWrite":false,
               "SingleRegisterWrites":"0",
               "UseModFun05CoilWrite":false,
               "singleCoilWrites":"0",
               "ClientPrivilege":"Read/Write",
               "ModbusDeviceBaseAddress":"1",
               "DefaultModByteOrd":true,
               "FirstWrdLowin32BitDT":true,
               "firstWordLowIn32Bit":"1",
               "ByteOrder":"Big-endian",
               "FirstDWrdLowin64bitDT":false,
               "firstDwordLowIn64Bit":"0",
               "ModiconbitOrd":true,
               "LongasDblePrsUD":false,
               "CoilOutput":32,
               "CoilInput":32,
               "RegInternal":32,
               "RegHolding":32,
               "PerBlockRead":false,
               "CloseTCPSocTimeout":false,
               "VariableImport":null,
               "VariableImportBTN":null,
               "IncludeDescription":true,
               "DeactivateTagIllAddrExe":true,
               "RejectRepMsg":false,
               "UseModTCPFrame":true,
               "LeadingByte":0,
               "TrailingByte":0,
               "ImportFile":null,
               "ImportFileBTN":null,
               "SelectObjs":null,
               "FilterOptProp":false,
               "CreateTagasRWAllowed":false,
               "USeObjNameTagGrpName":false,
               "BitsperRegister":"16",
               "IsModBusTcpIpSelected":false,
               "IsScanModeTextBoxEnable":true,
               "IsRTUSelected":true,
               "IsSelected":true
            }
         ],
         "PageVisite":false,
         "ChannelName":"Channel1",
         "DeviceDriver":"Modbus ASCII Serial",
         "EnableDiagnostic":true,
         "VirtualNetwork":"None",
         "TransactionsPerCycle":0,
         "NetworkMode":"Load Balanced",
         "PhysicalMedium":"COM Port",
         "ReadProcessing":"Ignore",
         "ComID":"6",
         "BaudRate":"9600",
         "Databit":"7",
         "Parity":"Even",
         "Stopbit":"1",
         "FlowControl":"None",
         "NetworkAdapter":"Default",
         "ReportConnErr":true,
         "reportConnectionErrors":"1",
         "CloseConnWnIdle":true,
         "closeConnectionWhenIdle":"1",
         "SecofIdleTime":0,
         "WriteAllTags":false,
         "LatesValNonboolTags":false,
         "LatesvalAllTags":true,
         "DutyCycle":0,
         "NonNormalizedValue":"",
         "SingleSocket":true,
         "MoreSocket":false,
         "MaxSocketsperDevice":0,
         "PortNumber":"",
         "IPProtocol":"",
         "SerializePortsetting":true,
         "OperationCommunications":false,
         "EtherNetSettings":false,
         "IsTagListViewVisible":true,
         "IsChannelListViewVisible":true,
         "ChannelSelectedItem":null,
         "IsChannelSelected":false
      }
   ]
}
```

My class is like below

public class Channel : BaseViewModel

```
 {

     RelayCommand _newDevice;

    public RelayCommand NewDeviceCommand
    {
        get
        {

            if (_newDevice == null)
                _newDevice = new RelayCommand(value => this.NewDevice(value as Channel));
            return _newDevice;
        }

    }
}
```

Here is properties...

Comment: message is 'CommandConverter' is unable to convert 'abc.RelayCommand' to 'System.String'.  Innerexception is null.

Comment: What version of Json.NET is installed on this old computer?  To find this out you can do `Console.WriteLine("Json.NET version: " + typeof(JsonSerializer).Assembly.FullName);`.

Comment: i have executed that & it is coming as Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Comment: There was a bug fixed in [Json.NET 5.0 Release 6](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2013/06/06/json-net-5-0-release-6-glimpse-plugin): "Fix - Fixed error deserializing interfaces with a valid type converter".  So if you were somehow using a version older than that on the XP machine it might be causing the crash.

Comment: I am using version dll 7.0.0.0 & runtime version is v4.0.30319.I am getting crash in serialization

Comment: Source for `CommandConverter.ConvertTo()` is [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Input/Command/CommandConverter.cs,e61c2c2b519ac558,references).  The exception is thrown if the `ICommand` is not a `RoutedCommand`.  So, what is `abc.RelayCommand`?  Is it a routed command?

Comment: it's an ICommand.But it will work if i am going serialize only a some properties in a class

Comment: Looking at the source further it seems the *current version* of `CommandConverter.ConvertTo()` only throws if `destinationType` is not `typeof(string)`.  But from the exception it's clear that it is.  So maybe you have an old version of PresentationFramework.dll on this machine and need to download the latest possible version for XP SP3?

Comment: i have added presentation framework 4.0.0.0.But no use again it is crashing.

Comment: In serializartion if i cahnge object like this    jsonObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(NodeConfigurator.Instance.Channels[0].ChannelName, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings()
                    {
                        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                    });  it is working correctly

Comment: Hmm.  From the traceback I still think it has something to do with commands rather than ReferenceLoopHandling.  How are these commands being used in your classes?  Can you make a simple class that contains this command and then try to serialize it?

Comment: i am following MVVM pattern.Shall i share my command structure?

Comment: It's more that I'm suggesting you pare it down to the simplest possible case that reproduces the problem.  From the JSON it looks like your current structure is pretty complex.

Comment: I have tried with code behind also.But still it is giving the same exception.It is tree structure so it is like that.I will try to do little simpler.I tried with simple class contain only one layer & it worked well .But if i use above JSON structure in that time it is crashing.

Comment: Then I guess it makes sense to share your current classes.

Comment: I am using static  singleton object in SerializeObject.Whather it is making any problem?coz after i made single layer also application is crashing.

Comment: @dbc I found root cause.I am using ICommand in View Model.It is binded with context menu.if i commnet that it is working correctly,i am susoecting that it is causing error.Please suggest what i have to do there?

Comment: I'm not entire sure since I don't have an XP machine.  Can you include a your classes so I try some alternatives?

Comment: I have added class which contain relayCommand. that class contain multiple properies that i didin't added here

Comment: @dbc I have fixed the issue by putting JsonIgnore in  relaycommand .Now it is not crashing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should amend your class, that you serializing and add `[JsonIgnore]` attribute to a member that leads to cyclic reference.

But you will need to assign this reference back when object is deserialized.

More info on `[JsonIgnore]` can be found in the official documentation: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_jsonignoreattribute.htm

Comment: I have tried this also but still i ma getting same exception.

Comment: Probably it is not circular reference issue then. Did you check the library versions on your both operation systems? Can you output the serialized string you received on W7?

Comment: i have posted the output in windows 7

Comment: Ya i ve checked .I have developed application using .net 4.0  i ve added corresponding version dll 7.0.0.0 & runtime version is v4.0.30319